# how to read and write a file larger than 4GB with NDK on Android Platform?

Tags: android-ndk, 32-bit

I'm learning the NDK．Because  Android is a 32bit system, and i'm puzzled that how to read and write large files larger than 4GB (e.g.,video file, .mkv) with EXT4? Are there some functions like write64 or something else?